# ns3 buffer.h assert failed

Tags: c++, ns-3

I created a new application for ns3, which seems to run correctly, however, after a few seconds of execution (after many packets have been received correctly), a get the following error:

assert failed. cond="m_current + delta <= m_dataEnd", file=./ns3/buffer.h, line=678

Any ideas what causes this error, and how I can bypass/correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an assumption, but it seems that you have a buffer overflow, i.e. the current size exceeds it's maximum size. Maybe you can clear the buffer or increase its size. As the message tells you, the error occurs on line 678 in the buffer.h file. You could look at this position to have an idea, which operation causes the assertion and maybe this helps you finding out what you have to do to avoid this message.

Comment: Thanx for the responce. I limited the application packet size to 1450 bytes, and is seems to run correctly. It seems that ns3 does not fragment oversized packets. I will try to fragment the packets at the application level and see if is solves the problem.